# Why is react routing not working with HashRouter on GitHub pages, but works locally?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

My React project runs perfectly on localhost, but when I deploy it to GitHub pages it breaks. I originally was using BrowserRouter, which I learned is not compatible with gh pages so I switched to HashRouter which does work when I run the project locally, but not on gh pages.

I have added the homepage element in my package.json file and have tried lots of other fixes and have had no success. Here are the parts of my App.jsx file concerning the routing:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { Routes, Route, Link, HashRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import Menu from './Menu'
import Order from './Order'

 return (

function App() {
        <HashRouter>
          <nav>
            <Link to="/" style = {linkStyle}>Menu</Link>{' '}
            <li>Cafe</li>
            <Link to="/order">Cart</Link>{' '}
          </nav>

          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Menu addItem={addItem}/>} />
            <Route path="/order" element={<Order orders={order} removeItem = {removeFromOrder}/>} />
          </Routes>
        </HashRouter>
  )
}
```

And this is my homepage tag in the packages.json file:
`"homepage": "https://<username>.github.io/cafe-react",`

I have tried adding /cafe-react/ to the paths of my route elements as well as changing the homepage to a few different things like adding a # at the end or just using the /cafe-react/. Any ideas where I am going wrong?